How to add the bounding box values to the labels text files during prediction with a trained YOLO-V8 instance segmentation model?
I trained a YOLO-V8 instance segmentation model to segment an object with class label 0. I used the CLI to instantiate the trained model and predict on the test data.
!yolo task=segment mode=predict model='/weights/best.pt' conf=0.25 source='/test/images' imgsz=1024 save=True save_txt=True save_conf=True

After prediction, the label files gets stored in .txt format. These label files contain the class index followed by the polygonal coordinates and finally the confidence score of the bounding box predictions. But, bounding box coordinates, that is, x-center, y-center, width, height are not included in the label file. I would also like to include these bounding box coordinates to each of the labels file since I would like to use these bounding box coordinates later for post-processing. A sample label file content looks like this:
0 0.21582 0.0898438 0.214844 0.0908203 0.213867 0.0908203 0.210938 0.09375 0.210938 0.0947266 0.203125 0.102539 0.203125 0.103516 0.201172 0.105469 0.200195 0.105469 0.199219 0.106445 0.199219 0.113281 0.200195 0.114258 0.200195 0.115234 0.203125 0.115234 0.204102 0.116211 0.223633 0.116211 0.224609 0.117188 0.227539 0.117188 0.228516 0.118164 0.230469 0.118164 0.231445 0.119141 0.234375 0.119141 0.235352 0.120117 0.248047 0.120117 0.249023 0.121094 0.251953 0.121094 0.25293 0.12207 0.254883 0.0927734 0.260742 0.0917969 0.256836 0.0917969 0.255859 0.0908203 0.233398 0.0908203 0.232422 0.0898438 0.910849

I am not saving the predictions to any 'result' variable here and I am running the predictions only in the CLI.

you can't use predict from cli to save bounding boxes because yolo segmentation save_txt argument only save the x and y for points of each segment. you should a separate write a python script for this job.
